# Redirect from a specific url to another url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want redirect a user from `https://app.salonized.com/c/5304/dashboard` (the page after logging in) to this page `https://app.salonized.com/franchise/reports/overview` using JavaScript. I tried some redirects but I lack the knowledge to get this done properly.

I tried this method but I think I'm doing it wrong:

```js
if
window.location. = "https://app.salonized.com/mobile"
else 
window.location.href = "https://app.salonized.com/franchise/reports/overview"
```

Comment: You haven't added the condition in your if statement

Comment: @KaranKiri Im really starting with javascript, could you maybe demonstrate how I do this  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need some proper synax.

'=' for setting and use '===' for comparing

```
if(window.location.href === "https://app.salonized.com/mobile"){
    window.location.href = "https://app.salonized.com/franchise/reports/overview";
}
```